# CSS2.1 validation fails for font-weight

Tags: css, w3c-validation

In the CSS2.1 standard, I see that `font-weight` exists:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness

But I get the following errors while validating:

```
50   h2  Value Error : font-weight 600 is not a font-weight value : 600
53   h5  Value Error : font-weight 900 is not a font-weight value : 900
95   div#logo    Value Error : font-weight 600 is not a font-weight value : 600
470  .contactInfoLink a  Value Error : font-weight 800 is not a font-weight value : 800
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore it. It's a valid value. There is probably a bug in the CSS validation software somewhere. The most notable one I've received: `Parse Error [empty string]`. Isn't that just a lovely and detailed error? Anyways, these errors sprout up on occasion. There's not really anything we can do about them.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparently a bug the the W3C CSS Validator, probably rather recent. It seems to report all numeric values for `font-weight` as errors. I have filed a bug report:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2012Mar/0015.html

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem as well; a google of the error I was receiving brought me to this question.  I happen to be experiencing not only `Parse Error [empty string]`, but also the `font-weight` issue, and also a validator issue with `word-wrap` that says `break-word` doesn't exist.

The `break-word` bug is confirmed [here](http://drupal.org/node/291384).  It sounds like the bug is quite old.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` has never been valid CSS, so that's not a validator bug. See [this question asked a short while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777554/validation-css-3-0-word-wrap-is-not-a-known-css-property-name) for details.

Comment: Oh really?  Okay then.  I was wrong. Thanks for clarifying :D