# Validation (CSS 3.0): 'word-wrap' is not a known CSS property name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I am using css 3.0 in order to use the word-wrap function and I get the following error. 
'Validation (CSS 3.0): 'word-wrap' is not a known CSS property name'. What do I do? I have the cascading version set for css3.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: What are you using to validate?

Comment: Just ignore it. This is simple and cross-browser solution, use it whether it validates or not.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`overflow-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap) instead:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's still a draft: http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap but older browsers (Firefox) support it

> This property specifies whether the UA may break within a word to prevent overflow when an otherwise-unbreakable string is too long to fit within the line box...
>
> ...For legacy reasons, UAs *may also accept ‘word-wrap’ as an alternate name for the ‘overflow-wrap’ property*. However this syntax non-conforming in author style sheets. (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap)

Comment: It's originally an IE property. Other browsers adapted it.

Comment: `word-wrap` was recently renamed `overflow-wrap`. Although both work, only the latter is considered valid CSS3. Why they renamed it is completely beyond me.

Comment: @BoltClock the name "word-wrap" could be proprietary :D

Comment: @Joseph: I'm pretty sure they had a better excuse than that.

Comment: @BoltClock Seems the WG thought `overflow-wrap` [was more descriptive](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Jun/0325.html)